# Не получается авторизоваться в phpMyAdmin при наличии nginx на 8080 порту

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, vps

Есть VPS. На нем есть **nginx** как back-end, он слушает порт **8080**.
Пытаюсь установить **phpMyAdmin**. Всё, казалось бы, просто: например, вот [инструкция](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-a-lemp-server).

Но дело в том, что если строго следовать инструкции, то при попытке авторизоваться происходит редирект сюда:

> :8080/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=1ab6355650f59ed4f2e66c3af79aee78

Видимо, из-за того, что *nginx* слушает порт 8080. Для решения этого вопроса я добавляю такой конфиг:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php;

    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /usr/share/;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-def.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 80;
    }
    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /srv/www/;
    }
}
```

При попытке авторизоваться возвращает на главную страницу без ошибок.
Через консоль авторизоваться в MySQL получается с этими же паролем и пользователем (*root*).

Как понять в чем проблема?
**UPD1:**
Поставил авторизацию - http ( в файле config.inc.php )

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';

Cмог авторизоваться, но любая операция кроме выхода вызывает ошибку

> ошибка несоответствие токена

В ПУ красный[image: доступ к mysql серверу] значок, который видимо показывает на отсутствие подключения к mysql ... 
Появляется почему-то только в chrome...

Comment: *Появляется почему-то только в chrome* — т.н. «сжатие трафика» (читай: проксирование), в браузере не включено, случайно?

Comment: Такого пункта в chrome не нашел, но возможно включено. Прокси отключено.
Там есть ускорение загрузки страниц, возможно из-за этого.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284?hl=ru

Comment: Спасибо. Нет , расширения нет и пункта в настройках такого нет.
Это не является для меня проблемой, поэтому не стоит тратить на это время.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге проблема была с этим параметром

> session.save_path

Который по умолчанию находится в php.ini.
Проблема была с установленным memcache , в настройках memcache были такие строки

> session.save_handler = memcache
>
> session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:11211"

После того как отключил memcache и установил значение

> session.save_path = /tmp

Все заработало.

Проблема так же описана [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546539/phpmyadmin-doesnt-work-if-session-save-handler-set-to-memcache)